# How to use dll of the project you referenced in Visual Studio C# .Net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Let's say I have a Project A in my solution. Project A has two dll's, Office.dll and  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.

I have another project in my solution which is Project B. Project B has a reference to Project A. So if we are going to check the references of Project B, it has ProjectA.dll on it.

I have seen a solution like this. If Project B is to be published (release mode) and we check its bin folder, it will also have Office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll even though these are not declared in its csproj. I am assuming that since Project B has a reference to Project A, it will also copy Project A's dll's.

Is this scenario can truly happen? Because I am trying to do this but im not successful on replicating it.

Comment: Hi eaon, This is right. You can change the properties of the office.dll set it  to copy local = false then it wont copy it to the output of your calling assembly.

Comment: It only copies the dll on Project A. I want it be copied also to Project B even though it has a reference only to Project A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your `CopyLocal on true`

Determines whether the reference is copied to the local bin path.

[image]

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984582(v=vs.71).aspx

[image]

Comment: It only copies the dll on Project A. I want it be copied also to Project B even though it has a reference only to Project A.

Comment: he copies A.dll on the bin/Debug of project B

Comment: but is it possible to copy also office.dll and  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to Project B, with Project B has only a reference to Project A?

Comment: You can copy in script post build of your application, you must add script

Comment: hmm... so referencing only ProjectA.dll in Project B does not directly mean that office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll will be copied in Project B's bin.... is there any other way to do this without using a postbuild?

Comment: postbuild stay elegant solution

Comment: Or also add a reference to these DLLs in the other project

Answer (score 0):

In the references for all referenced DLLs, view properties.  In the 'Copy Local' property, make sure it is set to true.

Comment: It only copies the dll on Project A. I want it be copied also to Project B even though it has a reference only to Project A.

Comment: And are the references that Project A has to Office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll also set to copy local?

Comment: By the way, are we talking about build from VS here, or some other build tool?

Comment: yep, Office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll  are set to copy local... yes, i use VS 2010